# IndentationError: writing data to csv

Tags: python, csv, scapy

I am trying to write 'data' from Scapy SNIFF to a CSV directly when python script for SNIFF is running, but I got the following error while running the script:

py_compile.PyCompileError: Sorry: IndentationError: unexpected indent (prog.py, line 33)

What is going wrong here?

Here is my code:

```
from scapy.all import *
import datetime
import csv
import sys

PROBE_REQUEST_TYPE=0
PROBE_REQUEST_SUBTYPE=4

STAMP = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()

WHITELIST = ['00:00:00:00:00:00',] # Replace this with your phone's MAC address


def PacketHandler(pkt):
if pkt.haslayer(Dot11):
    if pkt.type==PROBE_REQUEST_TYPE and pkt.subtype == PROBE_REQUEST_SUBTYPE and ( pkt.addr2.lower() not in WHITELIST or pkt.addr2.upper() not in WHITELIST):
        PrintPacket(pkt)

def PrintPacket(pkt):
print "Probe Request Captured:"
try:
    extra = pkt.notdecoded
except:
    extra = None
if extra!=None:
    signal_strength = -(256-ord(extra[-4:-3]))
else:
    signal_strength = -100
    print "No signal strength found"    
print "Target: %s Source: %s SSID: %s RSSi: %d"%(pkt.addr3,pkt.addr2,pkt.getlayer(Dot11ProbeReq).info,signal_strength)
f = open('/mtn/sda1/logger.csv', 'w')
filename = 'logger.csv'.format(STAMP)
    open(filename, 'a') as f:
           f.write('Target: %s Source: %s SSID: %s RSSi: %d"%(pkt.addr3,pkt.addr2,pkt.getlayer(Dot11ProbeReq).info,signal_strength)'.format(STAMP))
f.close()

def main():
from datetime import datetime
print "[%s] Starting scan"%datetime.now()
print "Scanning ..."
print "\n"
sniff(iface=sys.argv[1],prn=PacketHandler,store=0)

if __name__=="__main__":
main()
```

Comment: You have many indentation errors in that posted code.

Comment: Python has [significant whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884499/what-is-python-whitespace-and-how-does-it-work).

Answer (score 1):

you're missing the `with` keyword:

```
filename = 'logger.csv'.format(STAMP)
     open(filename, 'a') as f:
           f.write('Target: %s Source: %s SSID: %s RSSi: %d"%(pkt.addr3,pkt.addr2,pkt.getlayer(Dot11ProbeReq).info,signal_strength)'.format(STAMP))
f.close() # unnecessary
```

also, if you're using the `with` keyword, you don't need to close the file manually.

Comment: Thanks I still have a problem.. I put the 'with' in it and deleted 'f.close()' but now the error that I get is:

File "sas.py", line 33
f.write('Target: %s Source: %s SSID: %s RSSI: %d"%(pkt.addr3,pkt.addr2,pkt.getlayer(Dot11ProbeReq).info,signal_strength)'.format(STAMP))
^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

ANY IDEAS what is wrong with my code?

Comment: @Chrisvr http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html