# How does one make programs with string equality in Python?

Tags: python

Obviously, I've just started trying to make some random programs, and do not know much. A program I have tried to write is the following:

```
print('Please print your name')
myName = input()
if myName == 'No'
print('Fine, be that way')
```

There is an error in the third line, and am not really sure why. How would I correct this?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate question. Did you google or something before you asked this question. This won't be received well here I'd imagine

Comment: Your code does not follow basic Python syntax. Please do at least minimal research by consulting a book or tutorial before asking a question.

Comment: Yeah I did do about 15 mins of googling, I think I probably wasn't searching for the right things though.

Answer (score 1):

There's a syntax error in your code. The corrected code is:

```
print('Please print your name')
myName = input()
if myName == 'No':
    print('Fine, be that way')
```

[Here's another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884499/what-is-python-whitespace-and-how-does-it-work) that should help you understand the syntax berter

Answer (score 0):

if statements require a colon as follows

```
if myName == 'No':
    print('Fine, be that way')
```

python scope is implied by indentation, so you'll need to indent the lines that you want to be conditional, such as the print