# "expected indented block error " in python

Tags: python-2.7

am new in python and i made a program to add data from a  form to database am using wamp server here is my app.py code

```
import web
import MySQLdb
urls = (
    '/', 'Index'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

render = web.template.render('templates/', base = "layout")
class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
    return render.hello_form()


def POST(self): #Open database connection
try:
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "", "testdb")

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# Prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database.
sql = "INSERT INTO details(name, address,) VALUES ("[self.name.text, self.address.text])""
try:
   # Execute the SQL command
   cursor.execute(sql)
   # Commit your changes in the database
   db.commit()
except:
   # Rollback in case there is any error
   db.rollback()

# disconnect from server
 db.close()



   finally:


form = web.input(name = "Nobody", greet = "Hello")
greeting = "%s, %s" % (form.name, form.address)
return render.index(greeting = greeting)



 if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

and my error is Expected an indended block at line 12(return.render.hello_form)

can any one help pls..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scope is determined in python by indentation. As a result, you need to indent the `try` statement as it is inside the function `POST`. Also, the formatting on `finally` (and `db.close()`) looks wrong. Check out the [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884499/what-is-python-whitespace-and-how-does-it-work?rq=1), this [guide](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/block_indentation.hawk) and the [Pep 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guide on best practice code formatting. Also, be careful not to mix spaces and tabs as this can cause problems.