# AttributeError: 'PigMan' object has no attribute 'iAmFool' in Multithreading

Tags: python

I wrote a short example because I can't share my original codes. 
I think the problem was caused by python itself. 
Anyway, when I start a thread for a class, the program crashes if there are conditions. What is the reason? What is also the possible solution.

```
from threading import Thread
global dicta
dicta={"number":0,"name":"John","animal":"pig"}
class PigMan:
    def __init__(self):
        Thread(target= self.iAmFool).start()

        def iAmFool(self):
            if dicta["number"]==0:
                print("It's work")
            else:
                print("Wtf")
PigMan()
```

I expected it to run smoothly, but this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Pig/Desktop/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    PigMan()
  File "C:/Users/Pig/Desktop/test.py", line 6, in __init__
    Thread(target= self.iAmFool).start()
AttributeError: 'PigMan' object has no attribute 'iAmFool'
```

Comment: What version of Python are you actually running or have you tried this sample code on? Please observe good SO etiquette & tag it appropriately.

Comment: Yes i tried in py 3.5, 3.6, 3.7

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is off. [Python is whitespace-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884499/what-is-python-whitespace-and-how-does-it-work), thus the indentation of your code is critically important.

Reducing `def iAmFool`'s indentation correctly creates it as part of the class `PigMan`, as opposed to trying to `def` it within `__init__`.

```
from threading import Thread
global dicta
dicta={"number":0,"name":"John","animal":"pig"}
class PigMan:
    def __init__(self):
        Thread(target= self.iAmFool).start()

    def iAmFool(self):
        if dicta["number"]==0:
            print("It's work")
        else:
            print("Wtf")
PigMan()
```

[<sup>Repl.it</sup>](https://repl.it/@esqew/SteelAgitatedMozbot)