# try:/except: returns a syntax error in Python when trying to run module

Tags: python, syntax, except

Below is my code and the error is on line 4 "except" gives a syntax error... (this is a debugging and error catching assignment. I don't see what is wrong with it)

```
while True:
        try:
                userInputOne = input(int("How much time in hours a week, do you spend practicing? ")
        except TypeError:
                print("Oops! Practice time must be rounded to the nearest integer. It also needs to be a numerical value! ")
                break
    else:
        userInputTwo = str(input"How good to do want to be? Enter 'very good', 'good', mediocre, 'not good' ")
        if userInputTwo not in ('very good', 'good', 'mediocre', 'not good'):
            print("Please use one of the options. ")
        else:
            print("Let's calculate...")
            break
```

Comment: You have unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: And broken indentation.

Comment: how do I locate or correct that?
Unindent everything and redo it?

Comment: it's in the `userInputOne` line, but you should be able to locate it by reading the traceback of error messages too. they usually indicate where the error is

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Why are you being tasked with this with what seems like minimal experience in Python?

Comment: I found it all. Also, there was a lot that I found in just the part of the code I shared. Thanks. Resolved and working 100% now

Comment: Yes it is homework. He allows us to ask for help, but wants us to start trying and ask when you get stumped. Its my 3rd week of class (online).

Comment: Use an IDE that supports syntax highlighting and linting of Python code. The IDE can usually indicate syntax errors such as incorrect indentation and missing closing parentheses/brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Attached the working code.
Syntax Error was caused by missing parethesis and wrong indents. Take a look at your `else:` statement. It's not at the same height as the `try:` statement.
TypeError means, that you dont have to convert your input to strings, because they already are. Otherwise i suggest you create some variables and convert them via `int()` when you want to calculate with them.

```
while True:
    try:
        userInputOne = input("How much time in hours a week, do you spend practicing? ")
    except TypeError:
        print("Oops! Practice time must be rounded to the nearest integer. It also needs to be a numerical value! ")
        break
    else:
        userInputTwo = input("How good to do want to be? Enter 'very good', 'good', mediocre, 'not good' ")
        if userInputTwo not in ('very good', 'good', 'mediocre', 'not good'):
            print("Please use one of the options. ")
        else:
            print("Let's calculate...")
            break
```

Edit:
I recommend using PyCharm (if you don't) with its Auto-Indent function and nice "indent guidelines". So you can see many mistakes much easier.

Comment: I will get PyCharm. I have heard of it, but I wasn't sure if it was free or not.

Comment: There is a free version of PyCharm. I highly recommend it. After a while I actually found benefit in the paid version, too.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
while True:
        try:
                userInputOne = input(int("How much time in hours a week, do you spend practicing? ")
        except TypeError:
                print("Oops! Practice time must be rounded to the nearest integer. It also needs to be a numerical value! ")
                break
    else:
        userInputTwo = str(input"How good to do want to be? Enter 'very good', 'good', mediocre, 'not good' ")
        if userInputTwo not in ('very good', 'good', 'mediocre', 'not good'):
            print("Please use one of the options. ")
        else:
            print("Let's calculate...")
            break
```

To start off with, should look like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        userInputOne = input(int("How much time in hours a week, do you spend practicing? "))
    except TypeError:
        ...
        ...
```

Some ways I like to catch and fix this:

- Run [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) on your file. It will tell you where errors exist and give you warnings for code that can be improved.
- Use vim and the command `==` which will attempt to do some auto-indentation.

But the most important thing is to understand that [whitespace is important in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884499/what-is-python-whitespace-and-how-does-it-work). A syntax error of spacing exists throughout the file. You need to have four spaces rather than the eight in your code. Also, as noted in the comments above, you have some unbalanced parentheses which will break your code. In addition, you have an `else` statement without an `if`. Many problems all around, so I'd suggest re-working the code a few lines at a time and make sure that it works before moving forward. In addition, you cannot convert a string to an int, or at the very least you'll get unexpected results.

Comment: I’m sure that input(int( ... is not correct.

Comment: Good catch! Lots of errors in the code presented. Seems like OP was thrown into this assignment without much experience in Python.

Comment: Agreed!  Scott S.

Comment: Yes. I actually noticed it before realizing you pointed these out. I know it should be int(input(   however I'm guessing I just overlooked it due to them both starting with "i". It is 100% working now. Thank you!

Comment: Pleasure @hbss. Hopefully as you gain more experience with Python these errors stand out more easily. I'll take an upvote if it was helpful as well ;-)

Comment: Reputation isn't high enough to show it but I did upvote all answers. Thank you