# I get a IndexError: list index out of range Error

Tags: python, function, range

I´m having some troubles on my code, that implements a function that verifies the lenght of a string and return that string with or without spaces.

If String b >= 15 return b

If strinf < 15 return "number os spaces until len(b)2 +  string b

But I get a IndexError: list index out of range Error. I cannot figure out where or why.

Traceback:

============= RESTART: C:\Users\pbo\Desktop\Trab_04.py =============

ascii_letters = abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\pbo\Desktop\Trab_04.py", line 30, in 
    o2.append(a(o1[e]))

IndexError: list index out of range

=============  ============= ============= ============= =============

Thanks a lot for any possible help.

```
  from random import seed
  from random import randint
  from random import choice
  from string import ascii_letters

  seed(930)

  def a(b):

    if(len(b)<15) :
        s = "";
        l = len(b)
        while(len(s) + len(b) < 15) :
            s += " "
        s += b
        return s
    else: 
        return b


 print("ascii_letters = " + ascii_letters)
 o1 = []
 for e in range(9622):
         k = randint(1, 25)
         s = ""
 for l in range(k):
         s = s + choice(ascii_letters)
 o1.append(s)
 o2 = []
 for e in range(9622):
         o2.append(a(o1[e]))
 print("000000000111111111122222222223333333333")
 print("123456789012345678901234567890123456789")
 for e in range(9):
         print(o1[e] + "|")
 print("000000000111111111122222222223333333333")
 print("123456789012345678901234567890123456789")
 for e in range(9):
         print(o2[e] + "|")


 x1 = ""
 x2 = "a"
 x3 = "abc"
 x4 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
 print("000000000111111111122222222223333333333")
 print("123456789012345678901234567890123456789")
 print(x1 + "|")
 print(x2 + "|")
 print(x3 + "|")
 print(x4 + "|")
 print("000000000111111111122222222223333333333")
 print("123456789012345678901234567890123456789")
 print(a(x1) + "|")
 print(a(x2) + "|")
 print(a(x3) + "|")
 print(a(x4) + "|")
```

Comment: Please share the full traceback

Comment: `o1` only has one element in it (`s`), so any index > 0 will raise that error

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Posting your entire program for an untraced 3-line makes this hard to read for future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your [indentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation) is incorrect (see also [What is Python Whitespace and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884499)).

If you change the following:

```
o1 = []
for e in range(9622):
    k = randint(1, 25)
    s = ""
for l in range(k):
    s = s + choice(ascii_letters)
o1.append(s)
```

to:

```
o1 = []
for e in range(9622):
    k = randint(1, 25)
    s = ""
    for l in range(k):
        s = s + choice(ascii_letters)
        o1.append(s)
```

Then, your code appears to work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your list `o1` only has one element in it. Snipping out all of the rest of the code, you do this:

```py
s = "some string"
o1 = []
o2 = []

# now has one element
o1.append(s)

for i in range(9622):
    # when i > 0, IndexError will be raised
    state = o1[i]
    o2.append(a(state))
```

This happens because you are iterating over a range that has no relationship to the size/contents of `o1`. To fix this, you might consider:

```py
s = "some string"
o1 = []
o2 = []

o1.append(s)
for element in o1:
    o2.append(a(element))
```

The reason being is that now you are iterating over `o1` directly, rather than assuming it will always have 9622 elements in it, which it doesn't in this case.

Also, upon further inspection, it looks like your `a` function is just trying to pad a string with spaces out to 15 characters. Fortunately, there's a builtin for this:

```py
x = "some string"

x.rjust(15)
'    some string'
```

Where `rjust` will left-insert spaces to create a string of the given length