# Indentation error in if/elif/else python

Tags: python, indentation

I get an Indentation Error in the else part of this statement. I've checked it for white spaces and can't make any sense out of the error.

```
if cur_state == 'NICHTGEN':
    cur_state = 'GEN'
elif cur_state == 'GEN' and chance_num > trans_genZuGen:
    cur_state = 'NICHTGEN'
else:
    cur_state = 'GEN'
```

The exact error is

```
    else: 
        ^ 
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: You might be mixing space and tab characters

Comment: Remove all whitespace, and replace with spaces to see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Most editors for code / IDEs should have an option to replace all tabs with whitespaces. Make sure that option is turned on. This way you can never mix tabs and whitespaces

Comment: This problem just occurred to me on Ubuntu 14.04 with gedit as the editor, and I found the question and comments pretty useful. This is true, especially if your usual editor is not the one you're using at the moment, or if someone has messed with the tab settings, or if you started writing on one editor and had to finish on a different one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - you are probably mixing spaces and tabs.

Second - this logic can be reduced to

```
if cur_state == 'GEN' and chance_num > trans_genZuGen:
    cur_state = 'NICHTGEN'
else:
    cur_state = 'GEN'
```

or even

```
cur_state = 'NICHTGEN' if cur_state == 'GEN' and chance_num > trans_genZuGen else 'GEN'
```

(although the first is definitely more readable.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not using whitespace and tabulation for indentation in the same time.

Also see: [Are there any pitfalls with using whitespace in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637295/are-there-any-pitfalls-with-using-whitespace-in-python?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

Let Idle handle the spacing. Use the "End" key, the "Del" key, and the "Return" key on each line.